# How can I conditionally reference a figure?

Tags: cross-referencing, conditionals, knitr

So here's my knitr `.Rnw` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{}
\begin{document}
\let\ref\autoref

<<plot,fig.cap='try'>>=
if(rnorm(1) > 0) x = rbinom(1, 100, 0.5) else x = 0
big_number = x > 0
if(big_number) plot(1:x)
text=paste('I wish I could use it',x,'times a day!')
@

This LaTeX is fun! \Sexpr{if(big_number) text} \ref{fig:plot}

\end{document}
```

Here's my issue: when `big_number` is `TRUE`, then the pdf will be just as I like it:

[image: good]

If, on the other hand, `big_number` is `FALSE`, then the pdf will show a broken `\ref{}` as shown here:

[image: bad]

Is there a way I can hide the ugly `??` or make the calling of `\ref{fig:plot}` conditional on `big_number` or the existence of `plot`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the LaTeX side you could remove the **??** using an [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) of `\HyRef@autosetref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,etoolbox}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\ref\autoref}
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\HyRef@autosetref}{??}{\ignorespaces}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\label{sec:section}
See \autoref{sec:section} or \autoref{sec:sections}.
\end{document}
```

I would imagine it would be better to include the conditional placement of `\ref` inside `\Sexpr` somehow. I'm not familiar enough with knitr to know how that's done (if at all possible).

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the behavior of `\let\ref\autoref` so that the figure is labelled "Figure 1" rather than "1"? It seems to be lost with the `\patchcmd`.

Comment: @CephBirk: See the updated answer.